# "sufficient permissions" error for admin after duplicating WP database to new install

Tags: admin, database, capabilities

I recently copied the tables from a live WP install to a dev site for that same site. I've changed all the prefixes, the site/WP URLs, and the salt values.

I can successfully log into the new dev site, but the admin account (not actually named admin) does not have admin privileges. Once I log in and am redirected to the dash, I get the `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` error.

I've verified through the usermeta table in the DB that admin account has `administrator capabilities` and I'm out of ideas. Any thoughts on what I might have missed in the table migrations?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user within admin role?

Comment: I don't have an admin account working so unless you mean manually create one in the DB, I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: Yes, that was a dumb question.

Comment: So your table prefix matches that of the live site?

Comment: @vancoder: The two installs share a single DB. The live site has an empty string prefix and the dev site has dev_ as the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've duplicated the tables in the DB, with the new set having the dev_ prefix? In that case, the problem is probably that you have not updated the fields within the duplicated tables that inherit that prefix.

For instance, dev_usermeta will now have a meta_key called wp_capabilities. This needs to be dev_capabilities. Also, dev_options will contain an option_name called wp_user_roles. This needs to be dev_user_roles.

I'm not aware of any other instances, but I may be wrong.